Upload multiple files in Cloudinary with NestJS and streamifier
I am doing the upload multiple files in cloudinary. Below is the code I used for upload single file:
@Injectable()
export class CloudinaryService {
  uploadFile(file: Express.Multer.File): Promise<CloudinaryResponse> {
    return new Promise<CloudinaryResponse>((resolve, reject) => {
      const uploadStream = cloudinary.uploader.upload_stream(
        { folder: "FupartmentStore" },
        (error, result) => {
          if (error) return reject(error);
          resolve(result);
        }
      );

      streamifier.createReadStream(file.buffer).pipe(uploadStream);
    });
  }
}

How can I setup this service for uploading multiple files, because when I upload multiple file with this service method, it only upload the first file of the array.

Looking at your code you aren't iterating over an array but just uploading one file. Where are you looping?

For uploading multiple files, you would want a function that takes in a list of files then create an array of promises for the uploading then use Promise.all() to send the requests.

Based on my comment, this is the solution I was proposing.
@Injectable()
export class CloudinaryService {
  uploadFiles(files: Express.Multer.File[]): Promise<CloudinaryResponse[]> {
    return Promise.all(files.map(createUploadPromise));
  }
}

function createUploadPromise(file: Express.Multer.File) {
  return new Promise<CloudinaryResponse>((resolve, reject) => {
    const uploadStream = cloudinary.uploader.upload_stream(
      { folder: "FupartmentStore" },
      (error, result) => {
        if (error) return reject(error);
        resolve(result);
      }
    );

    streamifier.createReadStream(file.buffer).pipe(uploadStream);
  });
}

Another approach very similar to the above uses a file path (string) and the v2 cloudinary uploader.
@Injectable()
export class CloudinaryService {
  async uploadFiles(filePaths: string[]) {
    const filesToUpload = filePaths.map(prepareUpload);
    await Promise.all(filesToUpload);
  }
}

async function prepareUpload(filePath: string) {
  // Add fs import: const fs = require('fs');
  const byteArrayBuffer = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    cloudinary.v2.uploader
      .upload_stream((error, uploadResult) => {
        return resolve(uploadResult);
      })
      .end(byteArrayBuffer);
  });
}

